# Is the 64kb size limit to modules corrupting macros for excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm having random macro corruptions where I can't open the workbook.

I would have to disable all macro without notifications then open the workbook and recompile the macros, save close. Then enabled macros and open the workbook, then the workbook opens fine. Its almost like refreshing the macros helps reopen the workbook. I've checked some of my modules and a few are over the 64kb size. I've read some articles pertaining to module size limits that causes corruption.

Anyone verify if this is also for excel 365 or any reasons for macros to get corrupted?

Comment: Write smaller modules? Read up on *cohesion* and principles like *Single Responsibility* - your code will be easier to maintain, and you won't be dealing with module size limits.

Comment: well, the point is, i'm just wondering if it could be a factor for my macros to be corrupting? Also excel randomly closes when copy, paste text into other sheets within the workbook causing the same macro corruption.

Comment: *I've read some articles pertaining to module size limits that causes corruption* - the internal storage format hasn't changed in 20 years, what makes you think O365 changes any of that? The limits aren't the problem here...

Comment: FWIW the 64KB limit isn't on the exported file size / text source code, it's on the compiled p-code in the internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

The 64KB limit isn't on the exported file size, it's the maximum size of a compiled module.

If your module is less than 10K lines, if can be compiled.

A heavy but likely still healthy module would be 1K lines, tops - that seems to hover around 40KB when exported to a text file; 64KB doesn't strike me as completely indecent, although it *is* definitely above 1K lines of code, and thus could likely use some tweaks.

If your modules are named e.g. `Module8` or `Utilities`, verify how *cohesive* their members are - is it all related to the same functionality? Or does it feel like random functions were dumped in there?

Look for repeated code, refactor it. Extract methods, parameterize them, watch your module melt away, while retaining all its functionality.

The internal storage mechanics for VBA code, haven't changed in 20 years - I don't see a reason for that to have changed recently, especially since VBA is pretty much frozen now, and changing anything in the storage mechanics would break millions of things everywhere.

But, it's not impossible that something in O365 was changed recently (are you using an *Insider* build?), and something broke and your workbook somehow got corrupted.... but if your module is slightly above 64KB *of text source code*, it's very unlikely to be related: the compiled code would be much smaller than that... assuming the project compiles.

Comment: All my modules when exported, is below 64KB and a few in the 100KB size. The workbook only randomly become corrupted. Sometimes copy paste from sheet to sheet within the workbook causes excel to crash. Then on reopening of the same workbook, the whole workbook is corrupted and I have to do the process stated in my post to recompile the macros for it to be able to reopen and everything works fine.

Comment: The file size is irrelevant, only number of lines matter (storage size isn't shown anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 64K per *procedure*. To quote from [Procedure too large](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/procedure-too-large)

> When compiled, the code for a procedure can't exceed 64K. This error
> has the following cause and solution:
>
> - Code for this procedure exceeds 64K when compiled. Break this, and any other large procedures, into two or more smaller procedures.

I am using an 811KB VBA file in Access 2013. It has lots of small procedures, and has never caused any problems.

So, to answer the OP's question: if you have a giant subroutine somewhere in your project, break it up. Otherwise, the module sizes you report are nothing to be concerned about.